# Many-to-many in QueryBuilder

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

For my Symfony project I'm creating a form.
In this form a user can select an `Animal` entity, but only if it is part of any `Group` entity.

They are linked using a `many-to-many` relationship.
The `Group` entity has a property called `animals` which is a `Collection` of `Animal` entities.

Since I'm using a `many-to-many` relationship, three tables were created: `animal`, `group` and `group_animal`.

Now, if I were to use an SQL query, I would do the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM animal INNER JOIN group_animal ON group_animal.animal_id = animal.id
```

That way I'd get all animals that are in any group.

The problem is that I'm using Symfony's FormTypes and the only way I can execute a custom query is by using the `query_builder` option (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder)

I've tried many things but I just can't convert that simple(?) query into a QueryBuilder.

The closest I came was this:

```php
$entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('animal')
    ->from('App:Group', 'group')
    ->join('group.animals', 'groupAnimal')
    ->where('groupAnimal.id = animal.id')
```

It works, but now I have 2 tables in my "FROM" which does not feel right.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hello! You don't have an inverse side of the relation? Like a `groups` property on your Animal entity?

Comment: No I don't, I could add it though... would it be possible then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Use many-to-many bidirectional relationship**

Always use **->from('App:Animal', 'animal')->join('animal.group', group)** for table which contains data you want. Don't do the opposite *->from('App:Group', 'group')->join('group.animals', 'groupAnimal')*. For SQL you get same results but Doctrine can't handle it as you want.

Use inner join to retrieve only entities that are assigned to any group:

```
$entityRepository->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('animal')
    ->from('App:Animal', 'animal')
    ->innerJoin('animal.group', group)
```

More about bidirectional relationship: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

**2. Unidirectional one-to-many relationship (recommended)**

In this scenario you should break many-to-many relationship and create new connection table **App:AnimalGroup** which connect these two tables together. It is not convenient for all use-cases but it is more future proof, more simple to read and prepared for adding metadata for relation:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;

$entityRepository->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('animal')
    ->from('App:Animal', 'animal')
    ->innerJoin('App:AnimalGroup', 'animal_group', Join::WITH, 'animal_group.animal = animal')
```

In this case is up to you if you want unidirectional or bidirectional relationship. Bidirectional relationship is recommended only if child side didn't contains too many entries.